# Importrange function - what is the latest maximum data size that can be used? Changed late March

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google sheets changed the size of data that can be imported using the 'importrange' function in late March. We want to write a formula that can search through all our sheets and identify any that will be affected by Google's latest change.

We know there has been a change, as Importranges we had previously setup, are now returning "... to large" type error.

It appears to a limit of data size, not cells - as we experienced the issue on importrange of only 2 columns, but one contained large amount of HTML code in each cell.

Does anyone know what the data size limit is?
If not, then does anyone have an idea for best way to write a script that can find the limit?

Or next step will be to write a script that can search through our 'network analysis' sheet (sheet/tool that shows all Google sheets that are connected by importrange), and identify those with the importrange issue.

FYI - Google appears to have changed quite a bit relating to Google sheets and apps script.

a) We lost the ability to save changes in a sheet (making it basically unusable), which we think is related to having >50 importranges referencing that sheet (google support advised to avoid >50 importranges going to one sheet).

b) Other change we noticed is that google apps script can definitely now run for longer than the previous limit of 5min. We previously were seeing some scripts, sometimes running >5min, all the way up to a max of 30min. But now we see it consistently on some scripts. We built a tool, that can automatically get a script to 'run again' if it did not complete last time. We have had to tweak that 'run again script', to ensure it does not try to run the script again within 30min of the first run, to ensure that first script is definitely still not running.